# vuex state is not reactive

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

i am doing a loading spinner condition with vuex to handle the `loading = true/false` on multiple components.

`LoadingSpinner.vue`

```html
<template>
  <fulfilling-square-spinner
    v-show="loading"
    class="loading-spinner"
    :animation-duration="4000"
    :size="50"
    color="#007bff"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { FulfillingSquareSpinner } from 'epic-spinners';
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
export default {
  components: {
    FulfillingSquareSpinner
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({}),
    loading: function() {
      return this.$store.state.isloading;
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .loading-spinner {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 315px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
  }
</style>
```

i am using a third party loading spinner called [Epic Spinners](https://epic-spinners.epicmax.co/)
i wrapped up that to provide the same style and positioning on several other components.

This is how my store for the LoadingSpinner looks like:

```js
const state = {
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false
    }
  },
};
const getters = {};
const actions = {};
const mutations = {
  loading(state, isLoading) {
    console.log({isLoading})
    if (isLoading) {
      state.isLoading = true;
    } else {
      state.isLoading = false;
    }
  }
};
export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

i want to toggle the spinner to true before a axios call has started and toggle back to false when axios is done.

```js
this.$store.commit('loading', true);
or 
this.$store.commit('loading', false);
```

problem now is, the spinner is not reactive and wont toggle to true or false.
the computed property i am defining inside `LoadingSpinner.vue' is`undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure when you are using `mapState`, then why you are accessing through `$store`.

```
computed: {
  ...mapState(['isLoading'])
  // You can access `isLoading` as a property of `this` ex - this.isLoading

}
```

Now you can simply use the reactive property.

```
<template>
  <fulfilling-square-spinner
    v-show="isLoading"
    class="loading-spinner"
    :animation-duration="4000"
    :size="50"
    color="#007bff"
  />
</template>
```

Also you can use `mapMutations` for `mutations` too

```
methods: {
  ...mapMutations(['loading'])
  // it's get mapped as this.$store.commit('loading') and you can use as a property of this

  // this.loading()
}
```